# How to shut down ubuntu using exec (php)

Tags: php, ubuntu

I would like to shut down ubuntu in php script.

I tried this `exec("shuttown");` and `exec("sudo shuttown");`, but it didn't work.

Comment: One way of troubleshooting would be to run the commands in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exec("shutdown -h now");
```

It's a scary thought though that you would want a PHP script to have root privileges though

Answer (score 2):

The command is `shutdown`, and it requires a time given:

```
exec("shutdown now");
```

Also note that only root can run `shutdown`.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right; you have just misspelled `shutdown`, and have not given a time to shutdown.

As Tim Nordenfur said, simply calling `shutdown now` will execute that command.

For future reference, if you want to shutdown and restart it is `exec("sudo shutdown -r now");`.

Comment: Would PHP handle the `sudo` prompt?

Comment: @Tim: if PHP was run with a terminal connected - probably.  If it was run with no terminal (e.g. from a web server), then `sudo` would probably recognize that there's no opportunity to validate the user by getting the password - and would reject the attempt to become super-user.  So '*not reliably*' might be a good summary.